# How to make stackview disappear when scrolling down and re-appear when scrolling up?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, constraints, uistackview

I created a stack view with 2 buttons called

> Services and Customize

My goal is to make this stack view disappear when I scroll down and make it appear again when I scroll up. Everything works as it should be when I scroll down but when I scroll up, the stack view, I named it

```
menuStack
```

it overlaps with the tableview. The tableView is the one that contains images of a shoe as you can see in the screenshot.

I tried this delegate for scrollview but I think something is missing in my anchors. Here are 3 screenshots of each events.

[This is the default view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1u09.jpg)

[When I scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvTHV.jpg)

[When I scroll up the menuStack does not reappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyTmk.jpg)

```
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    self.menuStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if targetContentOffset.pointee.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        //scroll up

        self.menuStack.isHidden = true
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let safeGuide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
            self.menuStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
            self.menuStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
            self.tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }


        self.menuStack.isHidden = false

    } else {
        //scroll down
        self.menuStack.isHidden = true
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let safeGuide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
            self.tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When exactly do you want the stack view to appear again? Is it as someone scrolls up or is it when you reach the top of the scroll view again?

Comment: @Alan S Hi Alan, I would like for the stack to disappear when I scroll down. It is a header. When I scroll back up, I want the header or stack to reappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the scrollViewDidEndDragging function is called when the user lifts their finger off the tableView, this happens before the tableView starts it's deceleration animation. I think you should use scrollViewDidScroll instead. I tried this and it's working for me:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var menuStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
        didSet {
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        menuStackView.isHidden = scrollView.contentOffset.y > CGPoint.zero.y
        tableViewTopConstraint.constant = (scrollView.contentOffset.y > CGPoint.zero.y) ? 0 : 40

    //CGPoint.zero.y is when the contentOffset is at the top
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

I'll post a screenshot of the UI as well so you can see how my design is set up.

[image: Updated]

Comment: Hi Alan, it is working but I wish for the whole stack to disappear. Although the buttons disappear, when I scroll down there is still a white space on top of the table view. I wish for the menuStack to disappear completely(without white container) just so you can only see the tableView. Hope my explanation makes sense. Let me know if i need to send a screenshot

Comment: @松田Mr. I see. I've added something small that does that. I didn't set the top of the tableView to the bottom of the stackview anymore but directly to the top of the safe area. I outlet this top constraint to the view controller and in scrollViewDidScroll I adjust the value of this constraint to achieve what you want. It looks jumpy now but you could animate this constraint change pretty easily.

Comment: Also if this stuff helped you could you shoot me an upvote and if the solution works then possibly accept my answer